# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist - Hibernate with non-capital letters

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have the following error when I'm trying to map an entity:

**ORA-00942: table or view does not exist**

I figured out that the problem is that hibernate is trying to find the name of the table in "non-capital" (lowercase) letters, but Oracle has the tables names in capital letters (although the tables were created with non-capital letters).
I can fix the problem if I add the annotations **@Table** and **@Column** putting the names in capital letters, but I don't want to add those annotations.

I would like to know if there is any different way to do it.

Sql:

```
create table foo(
    id              integer not null
);

alter table foo
    add constraint foo_pk
    primary key (id);
```

Entity that **is not** working:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

    @Id
    private Long id;

//getter and setter
}
```

Entity that **is** working:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO")
public class Foo {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    //getter and setter
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Table and column names in Oracle are case-insensitive, so that should be causing problems. Could you post the code that's relevant to the question? However, you might run into problems when accessing data dictionary views for table metadata, because there the table/column names are indeed stored in upper-case.

Comment: Object names are case-insensitive only when not quoted:
OBJECT_NAME = object_name = Object_Name <> "Object Name". And ORMs use quoted notation in common.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom [NamingStrategy](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/NamingStrategy.html), to make the specific table and column names translation from your entity to Database. Here is some [example](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/implementing-a-custom-namingstrategy-with-hibernate/) how to do it.

So, all you need is to create an implementation of `NamingStrategy` interface or extend some of existing strategies, modifying it's behaviour with the behaviour you want to get and then register this new strategy via hibernate XML configuration parameter `hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy` or via Configuration class.

Comment: Thanks! There is NamingStrategy implementatios already created to do what I want to do?

Comment: Can't say at the moment, you can try those 4 existing strategies as simple java classes and simply check how they translate the names. If no one passes, just override one's methods for class and column names resolution